# Amazon RDS MySQL time zone

Tags: amazon-rds

Amazon RDS now allow to [change time_zone from Parameter Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.LocalTimeZone) but I couldn't find our country time zone Asia/Rangoon, +06:30 in time zone list.
How can I set this?